Throwing an exception in case of a rate limit exceeded
I got a gRPC service and a gRPC client written in C# with .NET 8. I have added a rate limiter to the service and I'm trying to throw an exception when the rate limit has exceeded and to catch it in the client. The service has this code on startup:
services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
{
    options.AddConcurrencyLimiter(policyName: concurrencyPolicyName, options =>
    {
        options.PermitLimit = 1;
        options.QueueProcessingOrder = QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst;
        options.QueueLimit = 0;
    });

    options.OnRejected = async (context, token) =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("The service is currently handling too many requests. Please try again later", cancellationToken: token);

        throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.ResourceExhausted, "The service is currently handling too many requests. Please try again later"));

    };

});

I know for a fact that the code gets to the OnRejected and throws the exception.
However, the client gets a different exception of internal status instead of ResourceExhausted. What can I do to fix it?

replace throw new RpcException() with return new ValueTask();

@HosseinBabamoradi I don't see an overloading of ValueTask which also receives a StatusCode.. How can I return a specific status code so the client knows to catch it?

Have you tried simply not throwing the RpcException?

@Fildor Then how will I catch the error?

If you have a 429 Result, what do you need an exception for?

Because its a grpc service, not a rest api. I don't send errors in the body of the message, but catch rpc exceptions I throw

Unfortunately, I haven't used gRPC yet. But knowing other RPC frameworks, I expected the client stub to throw that exception for you when it encounters a non-success network response code.

It actually does throw an exception from OnRejected, even if I remove the line which throws exception, but it throws with an Unavailable status code, and I can't seem to be able to control it to be a ResourceExhausted code

This is a little test project
using System.Threading.RateLimiting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
{
    options.AddConcurrencyLimiter(policyName: "rateLimitPolicy", options =>
    {
        options.PermitLimit = 1;
        options.QueueProcessingOrder = QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst;
        options.QueueLimit = 0;
    });

options.OnRejected = async (context, token) =>
{
    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
    await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("The service is currently handling too many requests. Please try again later", cancellationToken: token);
};

});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRateLimiter();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
    {
        var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
                new WeatherForecast
                (
                    DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                    Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
                ))
            .ToArray();
        return forecast;
    })
    .WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
    .WithOpenApi()
    .RequireRateLimiting("rateLimitPolicy");

app.Run();

record WeatherForecast(DateOnly Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}

and i call it with these codes
static async Task Main()
{
    int numberOfRequests = 10;

    var tasks = new Task<string>[numberOfRequests];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequests; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = SendRequestAsync();
    }

    Parallel.For(0, numberOfRequests, async i =>
{
    var result = await SendRequestAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
});

}

static async Task<string> SendRequestAsync()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7166/weatherforecast");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}

it return: Response status code does not indicate success: 429 (Too Many Requests).


Can you give an example with a grpc service and client instead of an asp.net one? The issue im having is having the error back as an RpcException which does not apply to your current example

Do you know how to do it for grpc?
